# How i can register component globally and define default behavior?

Tags: vue.js

It is possible, register component and define default behavior?

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import SmartSelect from '~/components/lib/smart_controls/inputs/SmartSelect'

Vue.component('smart-select', { onerror: Vue.myMethod($event), ...SmartSelect })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if you’re using Webpack (or Vue CLI 3+, which uses Webpack
> internally), you can use require.context to globally register only
> these very common base components

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Automatic-Global-Registration-of-Base-Components

define your default behavior inside your `SmartSelect` component.

if your meaning was to define a default behavior to **all** vue components, than you should read more about vue inheritance, which is a way to declare a base component with defaut behavior, and make other components to inherit and override that behavior. [here's a good place to start](https://medium.com/js-dojo/extending-vuejs-components-42fefefc688b)